# Rails showing objects without a foreign key relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-key-relationship

I've been hitting my head against a wall all day trying to do something I feel is probably pretty simple. I have a User model where Users can have Relationships (via following or unfollowing) with another model called an Interest.

On my home page, I want to show all the Interests that the @user or current_user is NOT "following."

I've been trying variations of this in my controller:

```
@interests = Interest.all.where(:current_user.following => nil)
```

Obviously, that's not going to work, since "where" seems to strictly search the database columns, and my relationship model doesn't leave any footprint in the Interest table. Funnily enough, I can easily show all the Interests my User IS following with a simple

```
@interests = current_user.following
```

I'm guessing I might have to write new resources and code for my model and controller for a "not following" method or route. But as a novice on Rails, I have no idea what that would look like, and I can't seem to find anything on Stack or elsewhere to help.

**UPDATE**

As requested, here is the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, 
          format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
          uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
   validates :address, presence: true
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id",
                        :dependent => :destroy   
  has_many :following, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed 

  geocoded_by :address do |user,results|
    if geo = results.first
      user.city = geo.city
    end
  end  
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?

  def following?(interest)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: interest.id)
  end

  def follow!(interest)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: interest.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(interest)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: interest.id).destroy!
  end
```

And here is the Interest model:

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "followed_id",
                        :class_name => "relationship"
  has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, 
                    :source => :follower   

  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a comment on @Ayman's answer:

> I am not sure how does your Interest model looks like or what does
>   following returns but I think something like this should work:
>
> Interest.where('interest_id not in (?)',
>   current_user.following.map(&:id))

You could try to use this query with `pluck` method:

```
Interest.where("interest_id NOT IN (?)", current_user.following.pluck(:id))
```

Comment: Specifically, this worked based on my model: `@interests = Interest.where("id NOT IN (?)", current_user.relationships.pluck(:followed_id))`

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should have a model which has all possible interests.

However, you can solve it using basic Array subtraction and `distinct` query on `Interests` in current scenario as well.

```
all_interests = Interests.select("distinct interest_type").map{|item| item.interest_type}
user_interests = current_user.following
not_followed_interests = all_interests - user_interests
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it seems after using this fix in my controller that I can no longer do any sort of call on interests objects used in my views. They're no longer acting like interest objects, so to speak.

Comment: @MatthewMelone Can you update the question with your model definition?

Comment: Just did! Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how does your `Interest` model looks like or what does `following` returns but I think something like this should work:

```
Interest.where('interest_id not in (?)', current_user.following.map(&:id))
```

Comment: This seems like it almost worked, but here is the error I received: 
      `PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
      LINE 1: ...rests".* FROM "interests"  WHERE (interest_id not     
      (74,83,77,...
                                                             ^
      : SELECT "interests".* FROM "interests"  WHERE (interest_id not   
(74,83,77,82,67,72,66,69,70))`